# Change the direction of Neocomplete popu

Tags: vim, autocomplete, neocomplete

I have [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) but it behaves counterintuitive. I want to change how the `<TAB>` affects the selection.

Current situation:

```
def<TAB>
```

Popup opens (This is an example, in reality there are much more and more complex items in that list):

```
def
+-------------------------------------------+
| def        [nsnip] def ${0} end           |
| defd       [nsnip] def delegegator_ end   |
| defs       [nsnip] def self.foo end       |
| defined?   [B]                            |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Nothing is highlighted, but the top one seems active. However, hitting `<TAB>` now highlights the bottom item. Hitting `<TAB>` again, the one-but last and so on. Tab cycles the selection from bottom to top.

```
def<TAB><TAB>
+-------------------------------------------+
| def        [nsnip] def ${0} end           |
| defd       [nsnip] def delegegator_ end   |
|*defs       [nsnip] def self.foo end*******|
| defined?   [B]                            |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I would expect `<TAB>` to move from top to bottom.

Is this a setting I need to configure? Is this the default behaviour but did I misconfigure something? Any setting or keypword to hunt for in my `vimrc`?

Comment: It looks like `<Tab>` is somehow mapped to `something<C-p>` while it should be mapped to `something<C-n>`. If the documentation of the plugin doesn't help you I suggest you use its issue tracker.

Comment: That was my first hunch, so I grepped my config and plugins for `<C-p>`. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are several conflicts with supertab. Since I was evaluating neocomplete as a replacement for SuperTab, removing the latter fixes the issue.

Neocomplete has no mappings for tab, by default, so the `<Tab>` does nothing. Adding configuration from the documentation makes `<Tab>` behave correctly:

```
" <TAB>: completion.
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```